# When assigning a value Java gives the error 'java: <identifier> expected', Why?

Tags: java, variables, char

When trying to compile the following class, Java gives the error `java: <identifier> expected`, Why?

```
 public class SingleCharacter {
    char aCharacter = 'A'; 

    aCharacter = '\u0041';

}
```

> `java: <identifier> expected`

- ***Answer***

The reason for the above-described error is because the second assignment(`aCharacter = '\u0041';`) is outside a method. A declaration and assignment, which is the first line(`char aCharacter = 'A';` ), does not cause such a disagreement with Java rules.

Comment: Can you please post full code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your're probably not using it in a method. Place it in a method as shown below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char aCharacter = 'A';

    aCharacter = '\u0041';
}
```

This is because assignments are statements and statements are allowed only inside blocks of code.